# How to authorize inline action of another contract within a contract?

Tags: smart-contract, inline-action

I deployed a contract omes.user.  In the reguser(account_name user) action of contract omes.user I want to send an inline action to another contract eosio.token to issue some tokens to user.

Here is the setup.
Create accounts eosio.token, omes.token, omes.user. Deploy contracts eosio.token and omes.user. Using eosio.token contract to create token OMES with omes.token as the issuer.

```
cleos push action eosio.token create '[ "omes.token", "1000000.0000 OMES", 0, 0, 0]' -p eosio.token
```

`omes.token` can now issues `OMES` tokens to accounts.

Add an permission `airdrop` to `omes.token` to authorize `omes.user`. 
Link the `airdrop` permission of `omes.token` to `eosio.token issue` action.

```
cleos set account permission omes.token airdrop  '{"threshold":1, "accounts":[{"permission": {"actor":"omes.user", "permission":"active"}, "weight": 1}]}' -p omes.token
cleos set action permission omes.token eosio.token issue airdrop
```

With above setup, `omes.user` can issue OMES tokens on behalf of `omes.token`.

```
easypayx@easypayxs-MacBook-Pro:~/eosio-commands $ cleos push action eosio.token issue '[ "user", "100.0000 OMES", "memo" ]' -p omes.token@airdrop 

executed transaction: f6543e4412f894a7522f131e9d551db7ebd932e1213e288a4f018c6c2f69a0bd  128 bytes  1875 us
        #   eosio.token <= eosio.token::issue           {"to":"user","quantity":"100.0000 OMES","memo":"memo"}
        #   eosio.token <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"omes.token","to":"user","quantity":"100.0000 OMES","memo":"memo"}
        #    omes.token <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"omes.token","to":"user","quantity":"100.0000 OMES","memo":"memo"}
        #          user <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"omes.token","to":"user","quantity":"100.0000 OMES","memo":"memo"}
```

Now, in the `reguser(account_name user)` action of `omes.user` contract, I want to call `eosio.token issue` action to issue some `OMES` tokens to user.

```
INLINE_ACTION_SENDER(eosio::token, issue)( N(eosio.token), {N(omes.user),N(active)},
              { user, asset(1000, S(4, OMES)), std::string("bid name ") } );
```

I have tried a lot different combinations for `N(eosio.token), {N(omes.user),N(active)}` using `N(omes.token)` and `{N(omes.token),N(airdrop)}` etc. None of them works. Here is the error I got.

```
Error 3090003: provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
```

So what is wrong with the calling of `INLINE_ACTION_SENDER`? Is this kind of operation supported by EOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem of permission name "active". Following issue is could be helpful.
https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3013

> We enhanced the security under Dawn 4.0, you need to set the
>   permission level "kc.code@eosio.code" rather than "kc.code@active".
>   Actions dispatched by code are no longer dispatched with "active"
>   authority, but with a special "eosio.code" authority level.
>
> ```
> eos@ubuntu:~/eosio-wallet$ cleos set account permission mk active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "EOS7ijWCBmoXBi3CgtK7DJxentZZeTkeUnaSDvyro9dq7Sd1C3dC4","weight":1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"ck.code","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p mk
> ```
>
> Therefore, the issue is a misconfigured authority on account mk.

In your case, you should have `{"actor":"omes.user", "permission":"eosio.code"}` instead of `{"actor":"omes.user", "permission":"active"}`

Comment: The solution decribed in that issue is to add permission `eosio.code` to user `omes.user`