# Can a smart contract bill the RAM storage to another smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract

I know that you can bill another user for storage but what if i want to bill another smart contract which in turn will then bill its users. Is it possible?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but assuming the permissions are right, a smart contract can bill any account, including one passed from a different smart contract in an inline action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as @confused00 mentioned in his comment, you can bill the RAM storage to either the account of the current contract itself (`_self`) or any account for which the transaction includes permissions. This means it's based on a per-transaction scheme, which means that for example:

1. Account `randy` submits a transaction signed by his account for an action in `contract1`
2. `contract1` can store something in DB billed to either `contract1` account or `randy` account
3. If `contract1` sends an inline action to `contract2` then `contract2` can store something billed to either `contract2` or any of the permissions given in the inline action to it (`contract1` or `randy`)

`contract1` can decide what permissions to pass on to `contract2` in the inline action.

In the documentation for `emplace` you can see there's a parameter for defining who is billed for the storage: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/reference#emplace

In the documentation for inline actions and permission levels you can see how to send actions and set the permissions: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/reference#structeosio_1_1permission__level

**EDIT:**
Also more related information here: [How to authorize inline action of another contract within a contract?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/how-to-authorize-inline-action-of-another-contract-within-a-contract)

Comment: Okay! Thanks for your detailed explanation!!!

Comment: No problem! If my answer was useful to you then please mark it as accepted. Thanks!